# How to pass ability in Harmony using Intent

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I was trying to pass ability like we pass in android

```
Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, cls);
```

But  in Harmony we have to use operation builder so used this method

```
intent = new Intent();
Operation operation = new Intent.OperationBuilder().withBundleName(ability.getBundleName()).withAbilityName(name.toString()).build();
intent.setOperation(operation);
```

Here 'name' variable is class name.

I just wanted to know that is this the equivalent of the above android code.
If not then what is the correct way

Answer (score 0):

You can construct an Operation object with bundleName and abilityName specified to start and navigate to the particular ability. The sample code snippet is as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();

// Use the OperationBuilder class of Intent to construct an Operation object and set the deviceId (left empty if a local ability is required), bundleName, and abilityName attributes for the object.
Operation operation = new Intent.OperationBuilder()
        .withDeviceId("")
        .withBundleName("com.demoapp")
        .withAbilityName("com.demoapp.FooAbility")
        .build();

// Set the created Operation object to the Intent as its operation attribute.
intent.setOperation(operation);
startAbility(intent);
```

For more details, pls refer to this [Docs](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-guides/ability-intent-0000000000038799).